# fetch all android contacts and details and put in single multidimensional array

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array

Am new to android(Java) and i want to perform a simple task
how can i Fetch all the contacts phone numbers, email, and fullname on the device and their details and put 
them in a single array as such
I am from a PHP BACKGROUND SO THE ARRAY WOULD LOOK LIKE THIS IN PHP :

```
 ContactsArray[0] = array(
                    'fullname' => 'John doe',
                    'Phone' => '0909809890' ,
                    'email' => 'johndoe@email.com'
                         )
```

Thats what the array should look like from a PHP perspective, 
Am new to android and would like a class to fetch all this data 
put them in a single array 
return the data.

PSEUDO CODE

```
     function GetContacts(){
     contacts = fetchAllContactsDetails
     return contacts;
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

This could be a start. Please note that I haven't tested this out and there could be errors but you'll get the idea.

Read this for more info on multi dimensional array. [Link](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/multi-dimensional_arrays.html)

```
String phpArray;
int x=3;
int y=array.length();
String[][] myStringArray = new String [y][x];

for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
        phpArray = contactsArray[i];
        myStringARray[i][j] = phpArray[j];
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but the main question was how i could fetch all the contact stored on the phone and put in a single array.

Answer (score 1):

First you need add the permission to read the contacts in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" > 
</uses-permission>
```

And you can check this code:

```
public void fetchContacts() { 
    String phoneNumber = null; 
    String email = null; 
    Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI; 
    String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID; 
    String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME; 
    String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER; 
    Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI; 
    String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID; 
    String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER; 
    Uri EmailCONTENT_URI =  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
    String EmailCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID; 
    String DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA; 
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer(); 
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver(); 
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);   
    // Loop for every contact in the phone 
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) { 
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
            String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( _ID )); 
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( DISPLAY_NAME )); 
            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( HAS_PHONE_NUMBER ))); 
            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) { 
                output.append("\n First Name:" + name); 
                // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact 
                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null); 
                while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) { 
                    phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER)); 
                    output.append("\n Phone number:" + phoneNumber); 

                } 
                phoneCursor.close(); 
                // Query and loop for every email of the contact 
                Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(EmailCONTENT_URI,    null, EmailCONTACT_ID+ " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null); 

                while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) { 

                    email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA)); 
                    output.append("\nEmail:" + email); 

                } 

                emailCursor.close(); 
            } 
            output.append("\n"); 

        } 
        outputText.setText(output); 
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: this works good, but how do i put the result in an array, like the format i mentioned above ?

Comment: I added some output.append, you need replace these lines for arrays, and add the values to the array. For example, you can use the lines of @Susie and declare:

`int i=0;`
`int x=3;`
`int y= cursor.getCount(); `
`String[][] myStringArray = new String [y][x];`

and replacing the outputs.append, you can write:

`myStringARray[i][0] = name;`
`myStringARray[i][1] = phoneNumber;`
`myStringARray[i][2] = email;`

and add `i+=1;` in each iteration

Comment: I got this error: the method getContentResolver() is undefined

Comment: `getContentResolver` is a method that belongs to subclasses of Context, such as an Activity.
You can use it into the context `Context context;`